# Using a VBA VLOOKUP with an Intersect in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that is used to enter instrument data and associated readings. There are multiple instruments entered from a validated list into a named range of "All_Inst". When an instrument is changed I need to clear out data in the row associated with that entry that is no longer applicable. At this data differs by instrument, I stored the various combinations in a simple 2 column table named "Delete_Data_TBL". From there I'm trying to use a `VLookup` to feed a case statement to clear the applicable cells.

I've successfully tested the vlookup outside of the intersect using a hardcoded value for the lookup value. I think the problem is using the c.value in the vlookup, but I can't find anything on what syntax to use. I tried  assigning c.value to a variable and passing the variable to the vlookup, but wasn't able to get that working either, though again I'm unsure of the syntax.

A somewhat simplified version of what I've tried is as follows;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Range
Dim d As Integer

'***Check if any ALL_Inst cells have been changed
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("All_Inst")) Is Nothing Then

    'Evaluate the cell that has changed to determine what should be set to ""
    For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("All_Inst")).Cells

        d = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c.Value, Sheets("Inst_Tables").Range("Delete_Data_TBL"), 2, False)

        Select Case d
            Case 0, 5
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 7).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 11).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 13).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 15).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 17).Value = ""
            Case 3
                c.Offset(0, 15).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 17).Value = ""
            Case 4
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 7).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 11).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 13).Value = ""
            Case 6, 7
                c.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
            Case 9
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 7).Value = ""
            Case Else
                'Do Nothing
        End Select

    Next

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize to stackexchange, i don't have enough reputation to make a comment but I think your problem is when `cl.value` is not found in the range. you can add in some error handling as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim c As Range
Dim d As Integer`

'***Check if any ALL_Inst cells have been changed
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("All_Inst")) Is Nothing Then


'Evaluate the cell that has changed to determine what should be set to ""
For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("All_Inst")).Cells

    on error resume next
    d = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(c.Value,Sheets("Inst_Tables").Range("Delete_Data_TBL"), 2, False)

    if isempty(d) = false then
        Select Case d
            Case 0, 5
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 7).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 11).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 13).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 15).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 17).Value = ""
            Case 3
                c.Offset(0, 15).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 17).Value = ""
            Case 4
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 7).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 11).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 13).Value = ""
            Case 6, 7
                c.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
            Case 9
                c.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 7).Value = ""
            Case Else
                'Do Nothing
        End Select
    end if
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That was it, Thanks!

Comment: It's good practice to cancel that `On Error Resume Next` as soon as you no longer need it.  You could avoid the need for error trapping by dropping the `WorksheetFunction` and testing for no match using `IsError(d)`

Comment: @TimWilliams, i agree and regret that i didn't add the `on error goto 0` immediately after attempting to update the value of `d`. I'm not sure what you mean by dropping the `WorksheetFunction` though, it seems that with the original question `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` is required to try finding the match in the first place... I personally would have used `Range("Inst_Tables").find(c.Value)` with various options and tested `If not d is nothing then`...

Comment: There are two ways to use vlookup (and other similar functions) in VBA: `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` triggers a run-time error if there's no match found, so you need error handling to deal with that possibility.  `Application.VLookup` will *not* trigger a run-time error if there's no match, but will instead return an *error value*, which you can test using `IsError()` - I prefer this approach since it's easy to handle the "no match" cases.